# How to retrieve data from MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a detailpage for my website where the information will be retrieved from the databse(mysql). I created a small php page where it does retrieve everything from my person table exept from my address table. My person table has a relation with address table. But when I output my person_address table which is connected to address_id it just shows the id and not the information.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, 
               person_email, person_phonenumber, person_cv, 
               person_address 
        FROM person";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["person_id"]. " -firstname: " . $row["person_firstname"]. "lastname " . $row["person_address"]. "email " . $row["person_email"]. "phonenumber " . $row["person_phonenumber"]. "cv " . $row["person_cv"]. "address " . $row["person_address"]."<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I am trying to program OOP and I hope you guys can help me. I am new to PHP and I know that my select query isn't good because I also need to select my address table but I am not able to change the query in a way that it will work. Of course later I will use Javascript and AJAX and i'll make a selection drop down menu where the admin can select address_city or address_state to show just the persons living in the selected area.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: your images are not clear at all, please post some bigger view.

Comment: I tried everything to make my pictures bigger. I think you can drag and drop them in your browser and it will show up bigger. I tried creating a link but it did not work.

Comment: Use join query :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844435/inner-join-mysql-tables

Comment: Your images show nothing useful. Do you actually have data in this row or are there just a lot of NULL's

Comment: @Anant With any pictures on SO (and any other website for that matter) you can right click and choose "Open image in new tab" (this is the text for Chrome, at least). It will [open in a bigger view](http://s16.postimg.org/r7r9lun2t/2016_02_29_10_44_12_localhost_8080_localhost.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing person_address here, which is ID in your person table.So you need to fetch the details from address table using this ID

For that you need to change your query:-

```
$sql = "SELECT person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, 
               person_email, person_phonenumber, person_cv,  
               address_street,address_housenumber, 
               address_city,address_state,address_zipcode 
        FROM person 
           inner join address on address.address_id = person.person_address";
```